# Progress bar for a lot of images

Tags: android, progress-bar

I'm making an application that downloads about 231 images, 150 of which are displayed in a list view while the rest are displayed full size in an image view in a separate activity.  The first time the app is run the images are downloaded which takes about 4 mins or 5 mins (I need a progress bar to show how many pics they have downloaded out of the total) and then after the images are downloaded they are saved to sd card. Consecutive launches of the app will then load the images from the sd card instead of re downloading them.

1. Is this the best way to go about this?
2. How do I make the progress bar? I am only successful at making a progress bar that works for one image

Answer (score 1):

The best way i know to do this is with an asynctask. As it will allow you to execute some background work and update the UI at the same time.(in your case, the progressbar).

This is an example code of how i would go about doing it..

```
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
mProgressDialog.setMessage("A message");
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
downloadFile.execute("the url to the file you want to download");
```

This is an example of how your AsyncTask will look.

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
    int count;
 try {
        URL url = new URL(url[0]);
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
        int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/somewhere/nameofthefile.ext");
   byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;
  while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
}
```

The method above ALWAYS runs in the background and you shouldnt update any UI from there.
On the other hand, the onProgressUpdate runs on the UI thread, so there you will change the progress bar:

```
@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(String... args){
    // here you will have to update the progressbar
    // with something like
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(args[0]);
}
}
```

You will also want to override the onPostExecute method if you want to execute some code once the file has been downloaded completely.

Comment: Will this say like (1/231) then (2/231) and so on?

Comment: Yes if you want it too..Where i have the message set in the progress dialog code you can update the progress message to say 1/10 downloaded or something in the onPostExecute method of the asynctask when the image is finished.

Comment: Maybe so. Post what you have in the question

Comment: I tried posting the code but it said i didnt do it writ and dont have edit permissions